# Does using classes in javascript instead of constructors give a performance hit?

Tags: javascript, performance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm assuming since classes in javascript are just syntax suger that class are being converted into constructor functions at some point, so I'm also assuming that his creates an extra thing for a engine to do, is this an accurate assumption?

```
 //Class, is this slower then a constructor   
class Employee{
    constructor(name,job,weeklyPay,age){
        this.name=name;
        this.breed=breed;
        this.age=age;
    }
    pay(){
        console.log(this.name + ": was paid " + weeklyPay);
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee{
     constructor(){
        this.reports=[];
     }
    addReport(report){
        this.report.push(report);
    }

    removeReport(index){
        this.report.splice(index,1);
    }
}

//constructor, is this more performant then a class?
function Employee(name,job,weeklyPay,age){
    this.name=name;
    this.job=job;
    this.weeklyPay=weeklyPay;
    this.age=age;
}
Employee.prototype.pay=function(){
    console.log(this.name + ": was paid " + weeklyPay);
}


function Manager(name,job,weeklyPay,age){
    Employee.call(this,name,job,weeklyPay,age);
    this.name=name;
    this.job=job;
    this.weeklyPay=weeklyPay;
    this.age=age;
    this.reports=[];
}
Manager.prototype=Object.create(Employee.prototype);

Manager.prototype.addReport=function(report){
    this.reports.push(report);
}
Manager.prototype.removeReport=function(index){
    this.reports.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: Test? I'd assume if it's a straight syntactic sugar translation, you might have slightly higher startup times to perform the conversion, but it would run at equivalent speed after.

Comment: I would not suggest choosing one approach in front of the other because of minimal performance improvements, if there are any. I'd suggest focussing on readability and if there eventually are huge bottlenecks then you'd look into it. You may also consider that different engines perform differently and that tooling often is used to convert ES6 code to older compatible formats.

Comment: You can test this by using Chrome's profiler. Open Chrome, press F12, select the "profile" tab, etc.

Comment: [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/es6-class-vs-constructor-function) says on my Chrome ES6 class is a bit slower. As Bergi says, it is likely it will undergo more optimisation in the future, just as it is likely other browsers might report different results (and the test itself could be better, I suppose - for one thing, time class definition and instantiation separately, because really, how often do you do class definition?)

Comment: `this.report.splic(…)`? Oops. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not accurate.

> I'm assuming since classes in javascript are just syntax suger that class are being converted into constructor functions at some point

Not really. Both are transformed into the internal representation of functions and objects, but that happens independently.

> I'm also assuming that his creates an extra thing for a engine to do?

No, "extra thing" implies that the `class` syntax would be translated into constructor function code which is then parsed as usual. This is only what happens when you are using a transpiler, but it's certainly not how an engine does it.

Actually, the assumption should be the contrary: `class` syntax comes closer to the internal representation of constructor functions, by conveying the *intent* to be used as a class it's much easier to optimise than plain `function`s which need extra heuristics. It's more declarative (does not need any mutation) and is designed in the spec to be easier to compile (e.g. by implying strict mode).

Comment: Does that mean there is a slight performance benefit to classes or is their performance about the same?

Comment: There is a slight performance *difference* because they're different things, but there's no real measurable benefit for either yet - engines still need to catch up with ES6. In the long term, `class`es are supposed to require less work by the optimiser to be optimised to the same performance.

Comment: Also, there are many different ways to measure performance: developer performance (because better maintainable syntax), network performance (because different code size), parser performance, compiler performance, optimiser performance, instance construction performance, method/property usage performance… They all will be affected by your choice. And you should choose `class` syntax if you don't know reasons to do otherwise.